# Looking for a reputable open dataset for BitTorrent or other p2p file sharing networks

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, file-sharing, storage-file-share

Hi StackOverflow community,

I'm looking for a reputable open dataset for p2p file sharing networks(e.g., BitTorrent) for research and experiments. Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

This one looks fine but the problem is that I can't find anyone using it, or used it in their research before. And it doesn't have information about how they collected the data.

https://github.com/Kiwi-Torrent-Research/Kiwi-Torrent-Research

Comment: What kind of dataset? A dataset distributed via torrents? Or a dataset about torrents? Or something else?